# Table-less form layout

Tags: html, css

After 4 hours on this , I think Ii have to declare myself defeated. I can't try any more float, position etc. styles to try to get this layout as I want it.
I would be ever grateful if someone could save me the rest of the day and the headache, of creating this layout in HTML without tables:
[alt text http://img142.imageshack.us/img142/4695/form2.jpg](http://img142.imageshack.us/img142/4695/form2.jpg)

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Post your work-in-progress code here and we'll fix it from there.

Comment: What are the requirements on the boxes? What dimensions should be fixed? What dimensions should be automatic (contractible / expandable)?

Comment: You might find something useful here: http://giveupandusetables.com/  sorry, I couldn't resist...  ;-)

Comment: was trying to get the code back to as i had it when it was semi funcional, but its really a mess. will have a look at the code posted below. thanks though!!

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.left {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.right {
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 0px solid black;
}
.wrap {
    width: 750px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 0px solid black;
}
.top {
    height: 25%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.bottom {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.middle {
    height: 50%;
}
</style>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">Left content</div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="top">Top</div>
        <div class="middle">Middle</div>
        <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The borders are messy and so are the widths but obviously it can be customized. :P

Comment: may i suggest changing all selector to classes so that he could use them for all three div blocks?

Comment: thanks, that looks a lot! like what i want.
my problem really accured when i wanted to have a different color on the border of each of the 3 div blocks. i need another div between "rap" and "left" for that dont i? before i can copy the above code 3 times to get 3 blocks.

Comment: Thanks Chetan. I always do that. :(
I don't understand, batman. Could you possibly make an image of it?

Comment: Try wrapping the content block you want to be red in a div (like you said) and then adding the style border-color:red!important; to all divs within that div. :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Salty's floats, you might try the ["no float" method](http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/css-layout/no_div_no_float_no_clear_no_hack_no_joke.asp).

For example (note, I have not tested this code cross-browser, but it's **modified** output from a no-float layout builder I built for internal use, which has gone through a lot of browser testing in the past; also note the caveat that IE 6-7 will **not** get the benefits of table-like layout, and columns will not be full height without some use of CSS Expressions... if you can predetermine the height, that's easy to overcome obviously),

**CSS:**

```
/* No-float */

/* Equivalent to <table> */
.lr {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    table-layout: fixed;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

/* Equivalent to <tr> */
.lcc {
    display: table-row;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Equivalent to <td> */
.lc {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 1px 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* <div> within cell to make styles across browsers more uniform */
.lccc {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1px 0 0 1px;
    margin: 0 -1px;
}
/* Adjust positioning in .lccc */
.content {
    margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
    *margin: 0;
}

/* IE 6-7 compat */
.lr, .lcc {
    *display: block;
    *word-wrap: break-word;
    *overflow-x: hidden;
}
.lc {
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    *width: 100%;
    *height: 100%;
    *line-height: inherit;
    *word-wrap: break-word !important;
    *overflow-x: hidden;
    *margin-right: -1px;
}
.lccc {
    *margin: -1px 0 0 -2px;
    z-index: 2;
}



/* Custom stuff */

.label {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
}
.field {
    width: 550px;
}
.field .content {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

form .lr {
    width: 750px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form .lc {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

/* Top and left padding are +1 */
form .lccc {
    padding: 16px 0 15px 1px;
}
form .content {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <div class="lb lr">
        <div class="lcc">
            <div class="lb lc label">
                <div class="lccc">
                    <div class="content">
                        <label for="field1">Field 1</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lb lc field">
                <div class="lccc">
                    <div class="content">
                        <input id="field1" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lb lr">
        <div class="lcc">
            <div class="lb lc label">
                <div class="lccc">
                    <div class="content">
                        <label for="field2">Field 2</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="lb lc field">
                <div class="lccc">
                    <div class="content">
                        <textarea id="field1" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Note that some of the CSS I put under the No Float section is not directly from the No Float site's method... it's stuff I've added based on lessons learned from conflicts between IE/standards-browsers and conflicts around padding, margins, and so on in the content. It's a little hackish and does require some attention when editing, but it's nice to be entirely free from float-based layout and it's surprisingly consistent.

Comment: yes, thank you!
i think it is the whole float thing is confused me and got me stuck in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article on using div tags and CSS for table layouts:

http://www.pixel2life.com/publish/tutorials/33/converting_tables_to_a_css_div_tag_and_xhtml_validated_layout/